# How can I sort rss feeds in a custom sort order to put into a React Native sectionlist?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-native, rss

I have an array of objects where each object represents an rss feed and each object has an "updated" field whose value is a timestamp in milliseconds that show's when that feed was last updated. I need to fit this data into a React Native SectionList.

I want to organize the feeds so that it looks similar to how Google Inbox sorts email, i.e. sorted by "updated" such that the sections are "Today", "Yesterday", "This Week", "This Month", and then everything else should just be grouped by month and year.

I've tried a number of different ways to do this but in the end, I haven't been able to get the sorting right. The closest I've come was getting the SectionList to render out something ordered like this: [...all the old stuff, "Today", "Yesterday", "This Week", "This Month"]

No matter how I tackle this I can't seem to put it in the right order. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best way but u could make 4 diferente arrays. Something like:

```
let lt1=lt2=lt3=lt4 = [];

myCol.map(item=>{
 if (item is today)
   lt1.push(item);
 if (item is yesterday)
   lt2.push(item)
 ....
})
```

And then, you could put all lists on the render:

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem title={item} />}
  renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Header title={section.title} />}
  sections={[ // homogenous rendering between sections
    {data: lt1, title: 'Today'},
    {data: lt2, title: 'Yesterday'},
    {data: lt3, title: 'This Week'},
    {data: lt4, title: 'This Month'}
  ]}
/>
```